# How to refresh the user claim, after Profile Update, IdentityServer3?

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I have successfully integrated the IdentityServer3 with an APP1 with OIDC JS framework, able to Sign-in , Sign-out. Things works great.

I managed to setup User Profile page part of IdentityServer3, I can navigate from APP1 to update the user profile. Works great.

After User Profile update (say LastName), I am able to navigate back to the APP1, works great.

Now the problem is, the LastName claim in the application side is still old. I tried to call login (2) (client.createSigninRequest()) still the lastName claim is not getting refreshed.

I tried to debug the IdentityServer3 server, when I call the login (2), it doesn't hit the

> GetClaimsFromAccount()

method.

What is wrong here, how to refresh the claim after say profile updates. Can you throw some light, how to overcome this issue, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

After a long struggle, mange to find the solution, you can find my solution in the below link.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/105

May be it will give some hint or approach, if any of you facing similar issue.